# Avoid using alias to identify the common column

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way using which we can avoid using alias for a table and set it as default option when a duplicate column scenario turns up? I have been looking for a way to do this in order to avoid going through every column reference and updating it to use table1 as alias.

E.g.:

```
select column1, column2, t2.column2, t2.column1 
from table (DEFAULT something that treats this table as default when no alias is mentioned against a column), table2 t2
where id = t2.id
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give us some sample or more detail?

Comment: Edited the question to include more details.

Comment: for future reference it would be an idea to not use the old style join syntax

Comment: Why will you want to avoid use alias name?

Comment: Because its cumbersome to stroll through legacy code over here and update the alias for every column, if I were writing it from scratch then I wouldn't mind.

Comment: I agree that we shouldn't use legacy join syntax, I am just maintaining a very old system. I am sure that many of you have been in the same boat as me.

Comment: @SadiqAli . . . Fix the legacy code by adding appropriate aliases.   You should leave code in a better state than you found it.

Comment: Already did but I was hoping I could do a better job than or lazier job than adding aliases everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no option to avoid putting table alias if multiple tables in query share same column name. Only way to avoid adding aliases when adding new table to SQL is to qyery this table in subquery or CTE and rename columns of new added table.

Comment: I will settle for an explanation as to why this feature is not present, would it cause some kind of an issue that I am missing?

Comment: This is not the only one reasonable feature missing in SQL standard. This also might differ between database engines. I have been working with Oracle, PostgreSQL and some other databases and each DB SQL has their pros and cons.

Comment: It doesn't seem that reasonable to me. You could suggest it as a new feature on the [Oracle Database Ideas](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/database-ideas) forum though.